# Youtube API fires onplayerstatechange twice on replay?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I noticed some odd behavior on a project I'm working on, so I decided to isolate my variables and take the bare-bones code straight from the youtube iframe API documentation, and I still see the same thing.
When my video plays through the first time, it all works as expected. But if I hit the "replay" button, onPlayerStateChange (with event.data==1 / "playing") fires twice, right on top of each other.
Any idea why this is happening, and how I could get the "playerstatechange" of "playing" to only fire once on replay?

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
        <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'cOgj_5lYijo',
          events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if(event.data==1){
        console.log("onplayerstate change happening: ",event)}
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I ended up getting a fix in place (I added a check in my code to make sure it's been at least 500 milliseconds since the last play) and that's working, I just wish I knew if the original issue was something with my code, or an issue with youtube's API.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, onPlay fires twice when I replay the video.
I tried different fixes, the main problem to resolve was that the video in the iFrame doesn't see the state changes of the component.

However, the video itself has a state that can be used.
Please note that this is pseudocode, this is not how you embed a YouTube video, you need to add an iFrame and all, but I wanted to focus only on the solution here. Also, it's a React component but the logic can be translated to other framworks.

I needed to add the effect hook because triggering the functonality I wanted didn't work within the switch case.

You can find the possible states of YouTube videos here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#onStateChange

I hope this helps other people save the time I took on resolving this :)
Comments on possible improvements are more than welcome!

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false)

  const handleYouTubeStateChange = (youTubeState) => {
    switch (youTubeState) {
      case 1:
        if (isPlaying === false) {
          setIsPlaying(true)
        }
        break

      case 0:
      case 2:
        setIsPlaying(false)
        break

      default:
        break
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isPlaying) {
      console.log('trigger the desired functionality here')
    }
  }, [isPlaying])

  return
    <YouTube
      onStateChange={(state) => { handleYouTubeStateChange(state.data) }}
    />
}

export default MyComponent
```